# Disconnect automattically after X minutes

Tags: cookies, session, logout

I recently discovered that if I don't disconnect myself from WordPress, my session could last for more than a day.

I wondered what could I do to set a maximum time of inactivity on the site, after which the user would be logged out. I guess that has something to do with the validity of a cookie, but I'm not sure about that.  How can I force a disconnect after a certain amount of time?

Comment: If you are interested to use plugin this can solve your purpose: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the "Remember Me" checkbox makes you get remembered for 14 days. This is filterable though.

add below code in your theme `functions.php` where 31556926 = 1 year in seconds

This code will change that value:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
    return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question do you mind explaining what is happening in your code for others.  if you did, I would be more prone to upvote your answer.